# Zurb Foundation Block Grid with different image size?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

This is my code from Block Grid example
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 my-grid">
  <li><img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/50098bda69beddb65e000008-480/iphone-example-camera-photo.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo2.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo3.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/ckMEN/1/

The problem I try to deal with is different image size. My backend will enforce to have `min width = x` and `min height = y` but how to deal the layout so that:

1. If width < height: crop and center the height
2. If width > height: crop and center the width

All images must have same `li` size though. Also how to deal when the window size changes, would that make the crop messy?

One alternative I have is to avoid using `block-grid` completely and just have **fixed size** of `li`. That is also OK too. So basically `li` will change wxh based on screensize.

But I prefer to play the trick if it works.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting the images as `background-images` you can have a bit more control over the cropping and positioning of the images in the `<li>` elements.

One downside to this is that you need to fix the height of the `<li>` elements. Though some simple javascript or a media query could correct this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-4 large-block-grid-4 my-grid">
      <li>
          <div style="background-image:url(http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/50098bda69beddb65e000008-480/iphone-example-camera-photo.jpg);"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div style="background-image:url(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo2.jpg);"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div style="background-image:url(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo3.jpg);"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div style="background-image:url(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/img/demos/demo4.jpg);"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-grid li {
    display:block;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.my-grid li > div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

**EDIT**

Added some jQuery to resize the height of the `<li>` based on their width.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function reheight() {
        $('.my-grid > li').each(function() {
            $(this).height($(this).width() * 0.75);
        });
    }

    reheight();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        reheight();
    });

});
```

And here's a [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/bsbdF/).

Comment: Didn't know javascript can be that fast... :)

Answer (score 1):

you could insert every image into a div with:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

and position the image in the center of the div,
then:

```
$("img").each(function(){

    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    if(height < width){

        $(this).height($("#div").height()); //if the width > height, set the image height equal to the div height.. 
            //let's assume that this image is into the div with id="div"
    }
    else{
        $(this).width($("#div").width());
    }

});
```